# Отсортировать массив

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив

```
$arr = [
    [ 'beg' => 75, 'end' => 75],
    [ 'beg' => 02, 'end' => 23],
    [ 'beg' => 75, 'end' => 48],
    [ 'beg' => 23, 'end' => 18],
    [ 'beg' => 48, 'end' => 02],
    [ 'beg' => 75, 'end' => 75],
    [ 'beg' => 02, 'end' => 02]
];
```

Нужно отсортировать так, что бы первый элемент следующей строки был равен последнему элементу текущей строки, С помощью PHP , что бы на выходе иметь :

```
[
  02 => 75 , 
  75 => 23
  ...
]
```

Comment: Где ваш код? Что это за столбики такие с цифрами в вопросе?

Comment: А что значит "есть массив", как эти цифры в нем лежат, в одном элементе массива обычно одно значеие, значит у вас массив массивов или какие то объекты... приведите структуру вместе с данными (array(...)), что бы можно было для отладки сразу в код скопировать

Comment: а давайте поможем Даше решить домашку

Comment: Да ладно вам, задача то кстати довольно интересная. входные бы данные увидеть

Comment: а какое отношение задача о домино имеет к сортировке?

Comment: Есть у кого нибудь идеи ?

Comment: народ помогите плиз

Comment: ни кто не хочет помочь ((

Comment: @Xfirab так нужно объяснять яснее..... а что у вас не получается когда вы пробуете?

Comment: Не знаю какой подход применить.
Вроде как циклами надо, но не могу сформулировать правильное увловие

Answer (score 1):

**Философский вариант.**

Just for fun.

```
function check($array){
    for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++){
        if($array[$i-1]['end'] != $array[$i]['beg']) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
$arr = [
    [ 'beg' => 75, 'end' => 75],
    [ 'beg' => 02, 'end' => 23],
    [ 'beg' => 75, 'end' => 75],
    [ 'beg' => 75, 'end' => 48],
    [ 'beg' => 23, 'end' => 18],
    [ 'beg' => 48, 'end' => 02],
    [ 'beg' => 02, 'end' => 02]
];

while(true){
    if(check($arr)) break;
    shuffle($arr);
}
foreach($arr as $a){
    echo $a['beg'].' - '.$a['end'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Для экономии времени можно записывать md5 от сериализованного массива в другой массив после неудачной проверки. Сэкономится немного времени =) А вообще любую задачу можно решить с помощью shuffle

Comment: Есть ли еще какие нибудь предложения или варианты

Answer (score 0):

Решал исключительно в качестве разминки для ума за 10 минут до конца рабочего дня, посему могут быть баги, неоптимальности и т.д. и т.п.

```
<?php

function findNext($curr, $arr, $out){
    if(count($arr) == 0) return $out;
    for($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
        if($curr['end'] == $arr[$i]['beg']){
            $next = $arr[$i];
            $temp = $arr;
            $out[] = $next;
            unset($temp[$i]);
            $temp = array_values($temp);
            $result = findNext($next, $temp, $out);
            if($result !== false){
                return $result;
            }
            array_pop($out);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$arr = [
    [ 'beg' => 75, 'end' => 75],
    [ 'beg' => 02, 'end' => 23],
    [ 'beg' => 75, 'end' => 75],
    [ 'beg' => 75, 'end' => 48],
    [ 'beg' => 23, 'end' => 18],
    [ 'beg' => 48, 'end' => 02],
    [ 'beg' => 02, 'end' => 02]
];

for($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
    $temp = $arr;
    $next = $arr[$i];
    $out = [$next];    // Эту строку надо было добавить
    unset($temp[$i]);
    $temp = array_values($temp);
    $out = findNext($next, $temp, $out);
    if($out !== false) break;
}

if($out !== false){
    foreach($out as $e){
        echo $e['beg'].' : '.$e['end'].PHP_EOL;
    }    
}else{echo "Solution not found";}
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/204c66b03a0ebbe67890639dbff0aaf896b6d6f2)

Comment: Код почти рабочий но есть недочеты 
    [ 'beg' => 75, 'end' => 75],

Comment: Код почти рабочий но есть недочеты 
один из 
[ 'beg' => 75, 'end' => 75] 
нет

Comment: @Xfirab а сами не хотите разобраться? Баг простейший и решается одной короткой строкой кода

Comment: Хочу разобраться, но не могу понять что куда надо добавить. (

Comment: @Xfirab первый элемент в массив `$out` не заносится. поправил в коде

Comment: а без рекурсии можно сделать?

Comment: @Xfirab можно вообще сделать по индусски, перебором всех вариантов вручную через `if`. Можно подойти как истинный даосист и завести бесконечный цикл с `array_shuffle`, пока не выпадет нужная комбинация. Можно обучить нейронную сеть на решение таких задач. Вы определитесь, чего именно вы хотите.

Comment: rjhdby Я на основе этого примера хотел разобрать свой другой массив, и в этом массиве может быть строки которые разрывают это цепочку. Поэтому спрашивал другие варианты

Comment: @Xfirab Ну вы бы сразу в вопросе все нюансы обговаривали. По какому принципу вы будете определять, что последовательность построена правильно?